# calling mssql on a remote server

Tags: sql-server

my remote server ip:62.128.xxx.xxx
mssql server name :"MyDB"

and i could connect to the data while on the machine with

servername: MyDB
Username: username
Password: password

what would the address to connect to the server remotely be. I've tried

62.128.xxx.xxx/MyDB. This doesn''t work.

Do i need to add any port or something

Comment: Can you please give some more specifics like the OS of the server and client and what you are using to "connect"? Then maybe you can get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've resolved this by allowing remote connections

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277

also, as my instance is the default i just needed to connected to the server

"62.128.xxx.xxx"